# ANGULARJS/JAVASCRIPT : error - Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and javascript . I am building a 'blog' using the above two technologies. 
My html view code-

```
<div ng-controller="Controller1">
<form  ng-submit="sub()" role="form">
Title: <textarea >

</textarea><br>
Body:
<textarea rows="10" cols="50">

</textarea><br>
Author:
<textarea>

</textarea><br>

 <button type="submit" onclick='sub()' >Submit</button>

</form>
```

but the problem is when I click on the **"SUBMIT"** button , it shows the above **error** in the console ie- **Uncaught ReferenceError: sub is not defined**

my controller code-

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('portal')
        .controller('Controller1', Controller1);

    Controller1.$inject = [ '$rootScope'];
    function Controller1($rootScope,$location) {

     var blog= { "article":
            [
        {
        "title": "Blog Post One",
        "body": [
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem deleniti quae, neque libero voluptate maiores ullam unde voluptatem assumenda velit dolores impedit quis qui! Neque, cupiditate labore nulla? Atque, tenetur.",
          "Numquam nobis nam voluptas blanditiis eveniet in quasi possimus voluptatem temporibus doloremque delectus dolorum, voluptatum laborum aut dolorem? In rerum necessitatibus soluta incidunt nihil numquam fugit quas pariatur dolores nesciunt?",
          "Quibusdam placeat quisquam iure repellendus ad in, nihil numquam quaerat, facere alias illo. Tempora perferendis incidunt, ratione eveniet esse earum, corporis sit? Modi enim commodi odio placeat minus, error id?",
          "Corrupti voluptates asperiores ratione laudantium, eveniet molestiae possimus deleniti officia, incidunt quae et. Amet, ducimus eum ipsa reprehenderit ad, et nihil, veritatis ea doloremque ab placeat dolore impedit, quia eius."
        ],
        "author": "Nick Moreton",

         },
        {
        "title": "Blog Post Two",
        "body": [
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem deleniti quae, neque libero voluptate maiores ullam unde voluptatem assumenda velit dolores impedit quis qui! Neque, cupiditate labore nulla? Atque, tenetur.",
          "Numquam nobis nam voluptas blanditiis eveniet in quasi possimus voluptatem temporibus doloremque delectus dolorum, voluptatum laborum aut dolorem? In rerum necessitatibus soluta incidunt nihil numquam fugit quas pariatur dolores nesciunt?",
          "Quibusdam placeat quisquam iure repellendus ad in, nihil numquam quaerat, facere alias illo. Tempora perferendis incidunt, ratione eveniet esse earum, corporis sit? Modi enim commodi odio placeat minus, error id?",
          "Corrupti voluptates asperiores ratione laudantium, eveniet molestiae possimus deleniti officia, incidunt quae et. Amet, ducimus eum ipsa reprehenderit ad, et nihil, veritatis ea doloremque ab placeat dolore impedit, quia eius."
        ],
        "author": "Nick Moreton",

        }


        ]
          };
          console.log('here');

            function sub(){

           localStorage.setItem('myStorage', JSON.stringify(blog));
            console.log('in sub');
            var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myStorage'));
            console.log('stored');
           $location.path('/another2.view');

           }

            }
  })();
```

So basically the onclick event isn't responding ie the **function sub()** is not getting initiated.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First thing don't call global function from Angular template which are modifying controller $scope(context) variables. It would not update bindings as it will not initiate angular digest system to update bindings.

Do use `ng-click` instead of `onclick` & expose that controller function in `$scope` so that it can be accessible on template.

```
Controller1.$inject = [ '$scope', '$location'];
function Controller1($scope, $location) {

   //Inject $scope in dependency array
   $scope.sub = sub; //add this line inside controller
   //other code as is
}
```

**Template**

```
ng-click="sub()"
```

But as you already calling `sub` on `ng-submit` you don't have to call it again on `click`, so just remove `onclick` event from `button`.

Comment: ok I did add **$scope.sub = sub;** . But it's showing more error plus when I add ng-click the button isnt working.

Comment: Have you exposed your sub function in controller $sco pe as I shown in answer

Comment: If you mean adding ** $scope.sub = sub;** then yes.

Answer (score 0):

First problem with your code is

```
angular.module('portal').controller('Controller1', Controller1);
```

If you have **not** already declared `portal` module somewhere else, you have to use this

```
angular.module('portal', []).controller('Controller1', Controller1);
```

then assign `sub` function to the `$scope` so that it will be accessible from the `view`

```
 $scope.sub = function sub() {
     alert("sub function called");
     localStorage.setItem('myStorage', JSON.stringify(blog));
     console.log('in sub');
     var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myStorage'));
     console.log('stored');
     $location.path('/another2.view');
 }
```

You can **remove** the `onclick='sub()'` and don't even need `ng-click` event if you have `ng-submit` on *form*.

It is [recommended](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action), within a form you should either use `ng-click` or `ng-submit` in order to prevent double execution of the handler.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SqJ9hWAVfGarFFKJpz1X?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

As above answered, sub() should be under $scope which will expose to the view. Normal function will be private to that function and will not available at view binding.